# Pull/merge uncommitted changes

Tags: git

I have two git working directories. As sometimes happens, I've made some changes in the wrong directory and would like to move those to the other one now.  That is, I would like to merge/pull the *uncommitted* changes from one place to the other.

In bzr I would use merge with the --uncommitted option, but I've been unable to find a git equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pushing and pulling inherently works on commits, so I don't think there's any way to do that, specifically.

However, you could just create a temporary branch (`git checkout -b tmp`), commit to that, pull it to the other repository (`git pull $OTHER tmp`) and then either continue from that commit, or revert HEAD to the latest commit while keeping the changes to the working tree (`git reset HEAD^`) and go on working on them that way.

**Edit:** Perhaps even more importantly, however: Are you sure you want to have two separate working directories? I can see that being useful in e.g. Mercurial or SVN (I haven't used Bazaar, so I can't speak for it), but in Git, you would normally use branches and stashes instead.

Comment: And yes, I want two directories. I have to actively work on both branches. Git doesn't concern itself with the binaries/build outputs, thus using checkout doesn't actually completely switch to the other branch (would leave outputs untouched). Sure, cmake/automake would rebuild as appropriate, but I don't want to wait.

Answer (score 3):

A low-tech solution is simply to use `git diff`:

```
$ cd wd_1
$ (cd ../wd_2 ; git diff -p) | patch -p1
```

You can the `git reset` in the other working directory.